# Need data from txt file, comma delimited, to populate an arraylist with objects from existing class

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I need to:

- take the input from a text file and read it line by line,
- take each line and split it into student objects and send those values to an arraylist,
- send the arraylist of objects from the Student class to my servlet,
- send the arraylist from the servlet on to my jsp page
- Display the values in an html table.

Here are my pages for this particular function. I have a number of different java pages, servlets, and jsp pages involved in this project so if you need anything from those please just ask.

The text file contains `Student` information in the following order:

> Student ID, Last Name, First Name, Quiz Scores 1-5, Makeup Quiz Score,
>   Midterm Score, Problems Score, and Final Exam Score.

and an example of the format of the text file is as follows:

> 1234,Some,Person,98.0,94.0,97.0,96.0,99.0,0.0,92.0,95.0,99.0
>   1235,Another,Person,89.0,99.0,87.0,85.0,88.0,0.0,89.0,98.0,99.0
>   1236,Onemore,Person,89.0,98.0,89.0,98.0,97.0,0.0,79.0,89.0,99.0

The output I am getting in the table however is the first line only and its all in the first cell.

If you could point me in the right direction I am completely lost.

Here is my `Student` class page:

```
public class Student {
private String sid,fnm,lnm,lgrade;
private double q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,qmkup,midt,probs,finex,qavg,cavg;

public Student (){
    //empty constructor
    sid="";
    lnm="";
    fnm="";
    lgrade="";
    q1= 0;
    q2= 0;
    q3= 0;
    q4= 0;
    q5= 0;
    qmkup= 0;
    midt= 0;
    probs= 0;
    finex= 0;
    qavg= 0;
    cavg= 0;
}



public String getSid() {
    return sid;
}

public void setSid(String sid) {
    this.sid = sid;
}

public String getFnm() {
    return fnm;
}

public void setFnm(String fnm) {
    this.fnm = fnm;
}

public String getLnm() {
    return lnm;
}

public void setLnm(String lnm) {
    this.lnm = lnm;
}

public String getLgrade() {
    return lgrade;
}

public double getQ1() {
    return q1;
}

public void setQ1(double q1) {
    this.q1 = q1;
}

public double getQ2() {
    return q2;
}

public void setQ2(double q2) {
    this.q2 = q2;
}

public double getQ3() {
    return q3;
}

public void setQ3(double q3) {
    this.q3 = q3;
}

public double getQ4() {
    return q4;
}

public void setQ4(double q4) {
    this.q4 = q4;
}

public double getQ5() {
    return q5;
}

public void setQ5(double q5) {
    this.q5 = q5;
}

public double getQmkup() {
    return qmkup;
}

public void setQmkup(double qmkup) {
    this.qmkup = qmkup;
}

public double getMidt() {
    return midt;
}

public void setMidt(double midt) {
    this.midt = midt;
}

public double getProbs() {
    return probs;
}

public void setProbs(double probs) {
    this.probs = probs;
}

public double getFinex() {
    return finex;
}

public void setFinex(double finex) {
    this.finex = finex;
}

public double getQavg() {
    calcStudent();
    return qavg;
}

public double getCavg() {
    return cavg;
}

private void calcStudent(){
    double[] qs = { q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, qmkup};
    Arrays.sort(qs);
    qavg = (qs[2] + qs[3] + qs [4] + qs[5]) / 4.0;

    if (qavg >= 89.5 && midt >= 89.5 && probs >= 89.5){
        cavg = (qavg+midt+probs) / 3.0;
        lgrade = "A";
    }else{
        cavg = (qavg * .5) + (midt * .15) + (probs * .1) + (finex * .25);
        if (cavg >= 89.5){
            lgrade = "A";
        }else if (cavg >= 79.5){
            lgrade = "B";
        }else if (cavg >= 69.5){
            lgrade = "C";
        }else if (cavg >= 59.5){
            lgrade = "D";
        }else{
            lgrade = "F";
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String s = sid + "," + lnm + "," + fnm + "," + 
            q1 + "," + q2 + "," + q3 + "," + q4 + "," + q5 + "," + 
            qmkup + "," + midt + "," + probs + "," + finex;

    return s;
}
```

Here is my java page:

```
public class StudentIO {
public static void addStudent(Student s, String path)
             throws IOException{
    File f = new File(path);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
    out.println(s.toString());
    out.close();
}

public static ArrayList<Student> getStudentList(String path)
              throws IOException {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
            (new FileReader(path));

    ArrayList<Student> sList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    String line = in.readLine();
    String data[];


    while (line != null){
        data = line.split(",");
        Student s = new Student();

        s.setSid(data[0]);
        s.setLnm(data[1]);
        s.setFnm(data[2]);
        s.setQ1(Double.parseDouble(data[3]));
        s.setQ2(Double.parseDouble(data[4]));
        s.setQ3(Double.parseDouble(data[5]));
        s.setQ4(Double.parseDouble(data[6]));
        s.setQ5(Double.parseDouble(data[7]));
        s.setQmkup(Double.parseDouble(data[8]));
        s.setMidt(Double.parseDouble(data[9]));
        s.setProbs(Double.parseDouble(data[10]));
        s.setFinex(Double.parseDouble(data[11]));

        s.getSid();
        s.getLnm();
        s.getFnm();
        s.getQ1();
        s.getQ2();
        s.getQ3();
        s.getQ4();
        s.getQ5();
        s.getQmkup();
        s.getMidt();
        s.getProbs();
        s.getFinex();

        sList.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));

        line = in.readLine();
        }
    in.close(); 
    return sList;

}
```

Here is my servlet:

```
public class ClassListServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String emsg = "";
    String path;
    String URL = "/ClassList.jsp";

    ArrayList<Student> stulist;

    try{
        path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classlist.txt");
        stulist = StudentIO.getStudentList(path);
        request.setAttribute("stulist", stulist);
    }catch (Exception e){
        emsg = "Process error: " +e.getMessage();
        URL = "/students.jsp";
    }
    RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(URL);
    disp.forward(request, response);
}
```

And here is the JSP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Class List</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Students on file:</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>    
            <th colspan="12"><br>Class List</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1">Student ID</th>
            <th colspan="1">Last Name</th>
            <th colspan="1">First Name</th>
            <th colspan="1">Quiz 1</th>
            <th colspan="1">Quiz 2</th>
            <th colspan="1">Quiz 3</th>
            <th colspan="1">Quiz 4</th>
            <th colspan="1">Quiz 5</th>
            <th colspan="1">Make-Up Quiz</th>
            <th colspan="1">Midterm</th>
            <th colspan="1">Problems</th>
            <th colspan="1">Final</th>
        </tr>
            <%

                ArrayList<Student> studt = (ArrayList<Student>) 
                                        request.getAttribute("stulist");

                for (int i = 0; i < studt.size(); i++) {
            %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= studt.get(i) %></td>
        </tr>


            <% } %>
    </table>
    <% 
       //cells and titles for each output field     
       //every time through loop will process each individual
       //student object instead of string objects
    %>
</body>
```

Comment: ok, so the extra instance is gone. I am still only outputting the entire string of each array of student objects on each row. I can't figure out how to populate the table with the individual objects in each cell

Comment: And the output still contains comma delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are populating sList in StudentIO.java, does sList contains all rows from a file? Try changing while loop to:

```
while ( ( line = in.readLine( ) ) != null ) {
```

Also, you are converting Student object to a string and then sending it to your JSP. Please pass complete List object and then print it. Also, you need colspan attribute in :

```
<tr>
    <td><%= studt.get(i) %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: yes, it is returning all of the lines of the file, but it is not putting them in each cell, it is returning it as a string just like the one that was read from the text file. I'm not sure I understand how to retain my objects across the servlet and jsp page from the java page so I can return each object in a cell instead of the whole string.

Comment: As answered by Sanjeev and Luis above, your sList object does not contain all Student objects.

Comment: How do I get it to contain all of the student objects?

Comment: I already removed the extra sList = new ArrayList<Student>();  instance, but I am still getting back delimited strings instead of individual student objects.

Comment: You are adding Student object in the sList and passing to JSP via Servlet. However on JSP, you are just doing studt.get(i) which will call Student.toString() method. Instead, in JSP you should do something like: <%ArrayList<Student> studt = (ArrayList<Student>)request.getAttribute("stulist");for (int i = 0; i < studt.size(); i++) {Student student = studt.get(i);%><tr><td><%= student.getSid(); %></td><td><%= student.getFnm(); %></td>...</tr><% } %> ==== Sorry stackoverflow.com comments does not allow formatted code.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! that was it. It FINALLY works. You can't possibly imagine how long I've been working on this one issue. You have helped me so much. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Glad that your problem is resolved! Upvote on answer can be another way of saying thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in `getStudentList()` method, You do not need to create a new `ArrayList` every time.

```
sList = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Must be moved out of while loop

Answer (score 0):

You're making an instance of the `ArrayList` on `getStudentList()`
Simply erase this line from that method `sList = new ArrayList<Student>();`